# C++ typedef syntax rules

Tags: c++

For the life of me I cannot find a good explanation of what are the rules that are used to convert a typedef to a C++ statement. The simple cases I understand. But consider this from [Danny Kalev](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=177):

```
typedef char * pstr;
int mystrcmp(const pstr, const pstr); //wrong!
```

Danny Kalev then writes:

> The sequence const pstr actually means char * const (a const pointer to char); 
>   not const char * (a pointer to const char.

I cannot find anywhere the rule to explain why "const pstr" would be converted to "char * const".

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This seems logical, no? You are defining `pstr` type as pointer to char. So `const pstr` is a const pointer to char, `char * const`.

Comment: Simple rule of thumb. `typedef` != `#define`. If you want what you are describing, you must use a macro.

Comment: If you use the post-const form consistently, it makes a lot more sense. `pstr const` == `char * const`.  The pre-const form is an exception and accordingly it can make things confusing.

Answer (score 5):

It's because `pstr` is an alias for `char*` and when you do `const pstr` is a bit like saying `const (char*)` and not `(const char)*`.

Comment: Thanks. This sheds some light on things. I still would be interested in knowing if there was documentation that shows that "const pstr" gets expanded to "const (char *)" and not "const char *".

Answer (score 3):

A typedef isn't like a macro; it doesn't just perform simple text replacement. The typedef defines a single unit, and the additional `const` applies to the entire thing. The unit defined is a pointer, so applying `const` to it give you a const pointer.

The outcome you expected would require the `const` to "reach inside" the `pstr` type to apply to something internal. It would get worse the more pointer levels were declared inside that type. Consider `typedef char*** pppstr`. To make that a `char const***`, the `const` would have to be inserted *three levels deep* inside the `pppstr` type. It's better for the rule to consistently apply `const` to the outer level, no matter how complicated the type definition really is.